# How do I automatically insert a row into parent table when a row is created in a child table?

Tags: mysql, trigger, foreign-key, insert

I am working on a MySQL database that has to treat organizations and people as interchangeable in some instances and not others. Because of this, I created a table called LegalEntity as a superclass. It has an optional 1 to 1 relationship with two other tables: Person and Organization. How I can make the database automatically insert a row into LegalEntity whenever I insert a new row into Person or Organization?

Comment: Use BEFORE INSERT triggers...

Comment: `<opinion>`That schema will cause you trouble`</opinion>`

Comment: Do you have referential integrity constraints for your super table (other than for the sub-tables)? If not you may be better of with a union view as "super" table